# Excel 2019 From Analysis Servicing Missing

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2019 and i trying to connect to Cubes through Data - Get Data - From Another Source - From Analysis Services but 'From Analysis Services' is missing.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under:

`Data` > `Get Data` > `From Database` > `From Analysis Services`